# Getting to Titan and beyond - technology knowledge management to get... anywhere

Tags: technology, research, computing

The article which made me to post this question is actually about (not yet) [getting to Titan](https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2016/11/03/what-would-it-take-to-get-humans-to-titan), but these words provoke thought for any space exploration target, please note it's a NASA engineer telling us:

> If we made a **list of the thousands upon thousands of technologies** that would be needed to “to achieve a manned, one-way mission to Titan”, we would find them scattered throughout the **nine TRLs**.

Is there actually some kind of interdisciplinary "space exploration technology database/information system" to research and analyze inter-dependencies of *thousands of technologies*? Obviously, they will be getting many more and also becoming even more complex. That is, "computer aided design" would involve actually a smart system telling you options and constraints pulling from existing experimental and historical data.

Who knows, maybe there is an ongoing research on something you will need a soon as it get to TRL X for your solution but just do not know it's name and can't Google it.

Comment: I don't see the question here @J.Doe. There obviously is a system of some kind to research these things because they stated that they made a list of the thousands of technologies required.

Comment: @GdD he says, "**IF** we made a list.."

Comment: Item 1:  What technologies are worse than humans at a) surviving, b) observing, c) working, d) communicating, e) getting upset at being lonely?

Comment: @Snow I beg your pardon?

Comment: I'm using a little humour to point out the fundamental question for a trip of this length: what is the need to send a human on such a long/arduous journey when automated systems can do the same job and better?

Comment: It would help if you defined what you mean by system @J.Doe. A system is a set of things working together to achieve a goal or perform a function - NASA is a system that is inter-disciplinary, and researches and analyzes thousands of technologies. It's how they put people on the moon.

Comment: @GdD NASA in sum yes: I'm talking though about an *information system*, don't think NASA lists, models and processes data about its technologies in Excel lists. This year they a rolling out a public cloud program.

Comment: This is really two different questions, with very different answers.  (1) What are the information systems that NASA uses to retain and search institutional knowledge?  (2) How does one find information on a subject when one does not know its proper technical name?

Comment: 1) should implement 2)

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't. Each space agency (NASA, ESA, Roscosmos...) has its own databases and repositories, and even within e.g. NASA one hand doesn't always know everything about what the other hand is doing or has been doing in the past. Apart from that, there are IP and political considerations keeping an agency from publishing, to other agencies, everything it has.

The only "database" of the kind you aim at, in your question, is distributed over the heads of many, many thousands of engineers and scientists.